# Get data from sites that needs authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a google chrome extension that gets data from other site, my question is: can I use javascript (or JQuery) to get data from sites which needs authentication?
i.e I want to get data from a site after I log into it using javascript.

I tried this code, but it doesn't seem to work!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#form").submit(function(event) {


  event.preventDefault();

  var $form = $( this ),
      us= $form.find( 'input[name="user"]' ).val(),
      pas= $form.find('input[name="pass"]').val(),
      url = "http://reg.ppu.edu/";

  $.ajaxSetup({

    username:us,
    password:pas

  });
  var posting = $.post( url, { email: us, pass: pas} );

  posting.done(function( data ) {    
    $( "#result" ).append( data );
  });
});

});
```

this is the site that I'm trying to get data the data from: http://reg.ppu.edu

this is the error I get:  Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

Comment: No this won't work this way. Check with them if they expose any Api that you can use passing in the credentials.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't :/ so it isn't possible to do it?!  :/